# Infinte loop when bad credentials are entered in spring security/form login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

As much as I have been able to determine it gets into infinite loop only when following bean is enabled on my . If this bean is enabled WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extended class.

```
@Override
@Bean(name = "MyAuthManager")
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

With this bean enabled, if I enter bad credentials, it gets into infinite loop. I have custom authentication provider extending from AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider. This class, as per contract throws UsernameNotFoundException if user is not found. I can see calls coming to my retrieveUser continuously.

Removing @Bean annotation, makes it work properly. But I need to access authentication manager at some other place.

Comment: infinite loop in terms of java or in terms of http redirects? I had a problem with infinite http redirects but I just have to define "failure URL" to some page that do not require authenticated user.

Comment: It looks like its in java - I throw UsernameNotFoundException and then I get a call back again -same thing repeats. Browser does not get a reply at all

Comment: @user871199 Did you manage to solve the problem? I have now the same. Please share the solution. Many thanks.

Comment: @jupi, whatever workaround I did is in the next answer. I am using this workaround and so far no other issues. Don't know if this is the right solution

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand all the mechanics of things get glued together, but authenticationManagerBean was big clue. Somehow when spring security created authentication manager chain, parent manager was set to self manager if I use authenticationManagerBean. My solution was to set parent authentication manager to null in during configuration. It must be my mistake or lack of my understanding somewhere

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(null);
    }
```